# OBJ imported into Nifskope has no texture

Tags: texturing, export, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to Blender, so bear with me here if this question doesn't include all pertinent information at first.

I'm working with an existing mesh for Fallout3. The mesh has three (3) nodes, one of which I want to modify slightly. Using Nifskope 1.1.3, I exported the node to an OBJ file, then opened that OBJ file in Blender 2.71. In Blender, I trimmed away vertices until I had what I wanted, then I exported the object as an OBJ file.

Back in Nifskope again, I imported the OBJ file as a new NiTriShape. So far, all has worked as expected. However, the imported node will not show the texture applied to it, despite showing the correct texture path/file in both Nifskope AND Blender.

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong here - probably in Blender before the export - but I haven't had any success finding out what so far.

Any tips in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

***EDIT:*** I've tried pointing to other DDS textures, in case the problem was my custom texture. Same thing - just a flat gray with no texture applied. I also tried adding a BSShaderPPLighting node (incl. BSShaderTexture) to the NiTriShape, and pointing that to various textures as well. Same issue. I'm starting to think the problem is with the UV mapping in Blender, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Nifskope generally uses directories linking to textures stored elsewhere on your computer, rather than bundling the texture onto the .nif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the issue was exactly, but apparently it was with my export. After downgrading to Blender 2.49 and installing the Blender NIF scripts, I was able to export the mesh directly as a NIF (instead of OBJ, then NIF) and now the textures work properly.

By having both versions of Blender installed, I can work in 2.71 with its much-improved interface, then open the *.blend file in 2.49 to export it as a NIF.